# Excel count based on more than one criteria

Tags: excel, count, sum, formula

I am trying to generate count figures for numbers of occurrences within a dataset, based on the row and column headings of a table.  I have tried countif statements and sumproduct, but i can't seem to get it to work.

e.g.(where I have included only one of the variables and I have made AT:AT a column of 1s to enable it to sum)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Call Handling year'!AT:AT)*( 'Call Handling year'!AF:AF='Call Handling Month'!B28))
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, can you explain in more detail what result you are getting, why its wrong and what you were expecting. Also if would be useful to understand how your data is laid out

Comment: I have just tried =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDIRECT(B28),'Call Handling Month'!AF:AF, 0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDIRECT(A29), 'Call Handling Month'!AM:AM,0)))      Both with this and the above formula I am getting 0 values, which does that match up with the expected value of 9 from a pivot table (and a look at the raw data itself.  The formula is in a separate data sheet to the dataset which is located on the 'Call Handling year'!  sheet.  B28 and A29 in this instance contain text values which are found in the specified columns, e.g. a month (format 0417) and a name reference eg. AG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count based on more than one criteria is `CountIfS`. Here is a sample of its implementation:

`COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2])`
`=COUNTIFS(B2:B5,"=Yes",C2:C5,"=Yes")`

[The official MS article is here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

---

There is an option to use `Sumproduct` instead of `CountIfS`. Its like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B6=C2)*1)
+SUMPRODUCT((B8:B13=C8)*1)
+SUMPRODUCT((B16:B20=C16)*1)
```

[I wrote an article with examples about it here.](http://www.vitoshacademy.com/excel-use-sumproduct-instead-of-sumifs-or-countifs/)